# OSX 10.11.3 keeps crashing when logging in

Tags: macos, software-update, crash

When logging in on my MBP (from stand by) it crashes in the middle of typing the password, and goes back to the user selection screen. When click on my user icon, and then typing in the password again, it works. However all apps are reset, of course. i.e the browser tabs are gone, and some programs lose the unsaved work etc.

This started happening since updating to 10.11.3 from 10.11.2. Is this a known thing? Is there a solution?

My Macbook Pro is the 2013 Retina edition, if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try and Boot in [Safe Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262) by holding Cmd-Shift right after it boots.

Comment: or verbose mode (command + v on startup) to check for errors